# how can i change the header and the data in the mat table angular to be on the right side of the page?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

i am trying to use mat table in angular so i can have a table with data the problem is that the headers of the table fields are not in the right side but i want them to be  i used RTl but i did not work what should i do? 
this is my table right now
[image]

this is my html code

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8"  class="table"  >

    <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
          The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > NO </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> weight </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> symbol </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
```

this is css

```
 table {
        direction: rtl;
        width: 1300px;

      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a small Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cunndn?file=src/app/table-basic-example.html

You just need to add **dir="rtl"** to your html tag like...

`<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" dir="rtl">`